# function parameter with FLEX code

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have a code in MXML and ActionScript that I found in a Flex manual. The problem is with "val" variable that should be passed to the updateMyString() function calling statement as a parameter but it doesn't happen in the code. Why is that?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- binding/BindSetterAS.mxml -->
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.binding.utils.*;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            // Method called when myTI.text changes.
            public function updateMyString(val:String):void {
                myTA.text = val.toUpperCase();
            }
            <!-- Event listener to configure binding. -->
            public function mySetterBinding(event:FlexEvent):void {
                var watcherSetter:ChangeWatcher = 
                    BindingUtils.bindSetter(updateMyString, myTI, "text");
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Label text="Bind Setter using setter method"/>
    <s:TextInput id="myTI" 
        text="Hello Setter" />
    <s:TextArea id="myTA" 
        initialize="mySetterBinding(event);"/>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says that `BindingUtils.bindSetter` expects a setter function with one argument:

> setter:Function — Setter method to invoke with an argument of the current value of chain when that value changes

In this case the `val` parameter will be set to the current value of chain. You can read about it here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html#bindSetter

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`var watcherSetter:ChangeWatcher = BindingUtils.bindSetter(updateMyString, myTI, "text");`

the function is like this:

`bindSetter(functionToCall, objectToBind, PropertyToBind)`

So, you are actually binding `myTI.text`. This is passed as an argument to `functionToCall`, i.e. `updateMyString`. Got it?

Comment: This comment is no problem. It works with this comment suprisingly.

Comment: I know it works correctly but how does it happen that we do not pass parameter to the function ...and it still works.